# What is the meaning of "Make a love of someone"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

In Armin Van Buuren's A State of Trance 699, the host (Armin) said:

> It is always nice to see that this radio show is connecting people also in a romantic way, because Vladimir Toula from Russia **made a love of his wife** on the bus, on the way to A State of Trance 650 in U Track (I am not sure if I heard it correctly) last year...

What is the meaning of text in bold? Is it grammatically OK?

Answer (score 3):

You probably misheard it. Most likely, the phrase was

> ... Vladimir Toula from Russia **met the love of his life** on the bus...

**The love of one's life** means what a person loves most in life, usually referring to another person. In context, this most likely means that Vladimir met the person who is now his spouse or fiancee on that bus.

While I can't see a *grammatical* problem with "made a love of his wife", I can't imagine what it could possibly mean. I've never heard those words used in that way before.

Comment: Sounds cool. I should really have thought of that.

Comment: Clever answer ,  It could be an acceptable answer for me   :D